# Display two different text for one permission

Tags: ios, xcode, privacy

I need to display two different messages for `Privacy - Camera Usage Description` permission based on the view controller user reaches first. 
But I can only add one text in `info.plist` file.

For example if user first goes to  viewController1, I need to show a text for permission and if user goes to viewController2, I need to show a different text. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The permission text is set in info.plist, so you cannot change it at runtime.

The permission dialog is only shown the first time that you request access to the camera, so it doesn't really make sense to have action specific permission requests; once permission is either granted or denied there are no further prompts shown to the user.

Your permission text should describe why you need access to the camera, perhaps mentioning both uses.  Something like

> MyGroovyApp needs access to the camera to create awesome selfies and to scan barcodes

Before requesting permission you could display an alert that explains why you are going to request permission.  You can use whatever text you like in this alert.

Comment: 2 types of Users can log in to the same app! We need to set 2 different messages for both types of Users according to functionality.

Comment: @NarendraSorathiya As I said in my answer, you can't vary the message at runtime.  The message needs to be built-in to your app bundle in the info.plist.  If apps could change it then bad actors could display one message during app review and another after release.  You need to have a message that covers all cases

Comment: You're right! @Paulw11